# Is there any simple way to access installed programs?

Tags: unity-dash

Just installed Ubuntu for the first time... Is there any simple way to browse installed programs?

On Mac there is the Applications top-level folder... here I see Desktop, Documents, Downloads etc but no Apps? That'd be a good idea, no? *(is there some way to create this myself?)*

On Windows there is the Start menu...

Here it seems like I have to click the 'Dash Home' and then I can see 'Recent Apps' ... I can search for them (I'd rather not)

...or I can click the ruler/pencil icon at the bottom and see 'Recent Apps' and click to expand 'Installed Apps' ...ok that's all of them *- is it possible to get a straight list view instead of the hard-to-scan wrapped rows?*

Also, is there any way to get rid of the pointless random selection of 'Apps available for download' at the bottom?

Comment: I guess you are using Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: yes. very impressed with the smooth install. the UI is ambitious but still feels clunky in many places and there are too many initial 'WTF' moments

Comment: You could go the command line way **dpkg --get-selections > programs.txt**

Comment: and then you can view the list using gedit or your preferred editor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like "Applications" on the Mac, you could browse "/usr/share/applications"

The best way to get there is open "Home Folder" or "Files" from the dash, press '/' and type '/usr/share/applications'. I guess you could make a bookmark there by pressing ctrl-D.

[image: Content of /usr/share/applications]

Comment: thanks, my question was semi rhetorical... why is there no bookmark created for this (with a nice icon, under 'Computer') by default?

Comment: I love the fact that there is no link. It points you to work in a more productive direction: search instead of browse. I always preferred to start an application by typing its name rather than searching in a menu maze.

Answer (score 10):

#### *ClassicMenu Indicator* will do the job!

---

[image]

---

- To install it, open a terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+T`, and type:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:diesch/testing
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install -y classicmenu-indicator
  ```

Comment: I'd rather not have to install a 3rd party hack to get something so elementary, but thanks I may yet give that a try!

Comment: IMO its not a hack, but just another app providing a feature some want. Canonical made a choice to go with a particular launcher. Unless you need other features of Unity, you can always switch to the Gnome Shell UI as @Nick showed.

Comment: and how do I get this on my task bar after I have installed it ?

Comment: Good question Milk...I'd like to know how to get it there after the installation.

Answer (score 2):

This is something way too easy,i do not undestand what is difficult for you to find.

**For Gnome:**

Applications -> All your software seperated in categories

System - > System tools

Places -> Folders

[image]

---

**For Unity:**

Click on "Dash Home" at the top left corner of the sidepanel:
[image]

Then search for the program you want to open:

[image]

Comment: OP already said "is it possible to get a straight list view instead of the hard-to-scan wrapped rows?" -- which implies he's using Unity, so the Gnome Shell option is useless for him.

Comment: I would like to know who marked this answer down as it answers the question correctly.

Comment: @ izx,you are correct,but i wanted to cover the answer completely :)

Comment: @William i guess that was for the first sentence i wrote...

Comment: Well you answered it so +1 you mate.

Comment: thanks but as @izx pointed out this answer is all stuff I already mentioned in my question. But I'm curious... how did you get that 'Shortcuts' panel with 'Media Apps', 'More Apps' etc?? That looks better than what I get. I'm on 12.04 LTS

Comment: @LinuxBill This does not answer the question at all. It explains how to search for an app by name, which the OP clearly explained he already knows. He wants to *browse* his installed software, without knowing the name in advance. Like a launcher menu in KDE, Windows, etc. I'm not sure how this wasn't completely clear from the question.

Answer (score 2):

When you click the **ruler/pencil** icon at the bottom and see '**Recent Apps**' pay attention to the '**Filter Results**' menu. It is right after the '**Search Applications**' field.

I guess it is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can hide apps for download by expanding the Filter options and choosing "Local" as the only app source.

Answer (score 0):

Open **Ubuntu Software Centre**, then click **Installed**

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the Ubuntu Software Center and download the classic menu indicator it will appear on your side bar. Click on it and it will appear on the top bar.

Comment: duplicate of an existing answer

Answer (score 0):

For me Synapse is the best solution to open programs quickly. Works pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and writing the name program what you want to open, like on the image:

[image: Synapse opening Firefox]

To install follow this steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:synapse-core/pp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synapse
```

To auto-start the program when Ubuntu start, go to preferences and activate the option.