# Ubuntu software center/installed

Tags: sound

How do you get installed software like sound recorder to open for use when playing sound or music? For that matter how do get access, like on desk top for any installed software to display icon for use? If this is old question please direct me, new to Ubuntu.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/148103/47291

Answer (score 0):

After installing the app, you can search for in the Ubuntu Dash. When found, click to launch, which displays the app icon on the Unity Launcher panel (vertical left edge of screen). Right click the icon to display options, like Lock to Launcher. (If you don't Lock to Launcher, find it later in the Dash again.)